# Magento 2 Add new field to Magento_User admin form

Tags: magento2, adminform, custom-field, magento-core

I am looking for a good approach with add/update already prepared (by default) Magento User's (module-user) form. The form can be reached in admin panel by this path:

System > All users > [chosen_user] > User's main edit tab (Account Information)

Now I'm trying with using di.xml in my custom module where I specify dependencies:
`

```
<preference for="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main" type="Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main" />
<preference for="Magento\User\Block\Role\Grid\User" type="Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\Role\Grid\User" />
```

`

This is content that I've already made for a Main.php class

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\User\Edit\Tab;

use \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main as UserEditMainTab;
use \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;
use \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;
use \Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface;

class Main extends UserEditMainTab
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        Session $authSession,
        ListsInterface $localeLists,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $authSession, $localeLists, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var $model \Magento\User\Model\User */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('permissions_user');

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('user_');

        $baseFieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Account Information __ TEST')]);

        if ($model->getUserId()) {
            $baseFieldset->addField('user_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'user_id']);
        } else {
            if (!$model->hasData('is_active')) {
                $model->setIsActive(1);
            }
        }

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'user_image',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'user_image',
                'label' => __('User Image'),
                'id' => 'user_image',
                'title' => __('User Image'),
                'required' => false,
                'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, png'
            ]
        );

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'username',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'username',
                'label' => __('User Name'),
                'id' => 'username',
                'title' => __('User Name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'firstname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'firstname',
                'label' => __('First Name'),
                'id' => 'firstname',
                'title' => __('First Name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'lastname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'lastname',
                'label' => __('Last Name'),
                'id' => 'lastname',
                'title' => __('Last Name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'email',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'email',
                'label' => __('Email'),
                'id' => 'customer_email',
                'title' => __('User Email'),
                'class' => 'required-entry validate-email',
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $isNewObject = $model->isObjectNew();
        if ($isNewObject) {
            $passwordLabel = __('Password');
        } else {
            $passwordLabel = __('New Password');
        }
        $confirmationLabel = __('Password Confirmation');
        $this->_addPasswordFields($baseFieldset, $passwordLabel, $confirmationLabel, $isNewObject);

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'interface_locale',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'interface_locale',
                'label' => __('Interface Locale'),
                'title' => __('Interface Locale'),
                'values' => $this->_LocaleLists->getTranslatedOptionLocales(),
                'class' => 'select'
            ]
        );

        if ($this->_authSession->getUser()->getId() != $model->getUserId()) {
            $baseFieldset->addField(
                'is_active',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'is_active',
                    'label' => __('This account is'),
                    'id' => 'is_active',
                    'title' => __('Account Status'),
                    'class' => 'input-select',
                    'options' => ['1' => __('Active'), '0' => __('Inactive')]
                ]
            );
        }

        $baseFieldset->addField('user_roles', 'hidden', ['name' => 'user_roles', 'id' => '_user_roles']);

        $currentUserVerificationFieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'current_user_verification_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Current User Identity Verification')]
        );
        $currentUserVerificationFieldset->addField(
            self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD,
            'password',
            [
                'name' => self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD,
                'label' => __('Your Password'),
                'id' => self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD,
                'title' => __('Your Password'),
                'class' => 'input-text validate-current-password required-entry',
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $data = $model->getData();
        unset($data['password']);
        unset($data[self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD]);
        $form->setValues($data);

        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

and some code for User.php

```
namespace Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Block\Role\Grid;

use \Magento\User\Block\Role\Grid\User as RoleGridUser;
use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended as ExtendedGrid;

class User extends RoleGridUser
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareCollection();

        $this->addColumn(
            'user_image',
            [
                'header' => __('User Image'),
                'width' => 5,
                'align' => 'left',
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'user_image'
            ]
        );

        return ExtendedGrid::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

If you take a look closer you already now that I'm trying to add a field with user's image.

Unfortunately, I don't see any changes in admin front. Of course, the needed column was added by InstallSchema script earlier to '**admin_user**' table.

Contents of directories in a tree-like format:

```
Module_Name
├── Block
│   ├── Catalog
│   │   └── Product
│   │       └── RelatedPosts.php
│   ├── Role
│   │   └── Grid
│   │       └── User.php
│   └── User
│       └── Edit
│           └── Tab
│               └── Main.php
├── composer.json
├── etc
│   ├── di.xml
│   └── module.xml
├── Setup
    └── InstallSchema.php
```

What Did I do Wrong?

Comment: The above solution is great but the values are not set on the added fields..is there anything else we need to do on the same. We are basically overriding the Reviews form. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For adding image field, you can try using plugin and always try to avoid overwrite whole class.

**Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main">
        <plugin name="sr_stackexchange_user_form" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab\Main" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/User/Edit/Tab/Main.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab;

class Main
{
    /**
     * Get form HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('admin_user_image', ['legend' => __('User Image')]);
            $fieldset->addField(
                'user_image',
                'image',
                [
                    'name' => 'user_image',
                    'label' => __('Image'),
                    'id' => 'user_image',
                    'title' => __('Image'),
                    'required' => false,
                    'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, png'
                ]
            );

            $subject->setForm($form);
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Hey Sohel, thanks a lot for your response! It seems to be exact what I want to achieve :) I'll give you feedback as soon as I try this code locally. By the way, I saw that you create new fieldset and I'm starting to wonder if it's possible to update already existing one, e.g. 'base_fieldset', what do you think? Also, I am curious, is this plugin approach cover updating controllers too? I need to update some thinks in future here: `/module-user/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Save.php` - save string with image's path in  'admin_user' table. Sorry about many questions. appreciate your help! cheers!

Comment: Ok, it's possible to use plugin for a controller, but in my case that was not sufficient. Anyway, your suggestions help me to resolve a problem. Thank you once again!

Comment: The above solution is great but the values are not set on the added fields..is there anything else we need to do on the same.

We are basically overriding the Reviews form.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I would also be interested in how to save the value of a new field in admin user form to admin_user table. Did you solve it extending/overriding the /module-user/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Save.php Controller?

Comment: @Sohel Rana, selected field will not show where ? or how to we can get current user id here ?

Comment: @hallleron first of all you need to add the column in the table admin_user in install script. And next to show the saved value in the edit form you can do it by $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('user_image'); make sure to initialize _coreRegistry in plugin constructor and   in the end add value field in the form field like 'value' => $model->getData('user_image')

Comment: Kindly help me , I have trouble in showing that image in edit form ..I have used above code only

Comment: @Sohelrana, I am able to add field in form using your code, but it is not showing values when we edit form

Comment: You should use a before plugin instead of a around plugin. Magento recommends to avoid using around methods plugins because they affect performance and increase stack traces.

Comment: 1. Adding to an existing fieldset Eg:$fieldset=$form->getElement('base_fieldset'); $fieldset->addField(..); After setForm();$res=$sub->getForm()->getHtml();
2. To save the new field, need to create a beforeSave pugin to Magento\User\Model\User and eg:if ($timezone = $this->request->getParam('user_timezone')){ $subject->setData('user_timezone', $timezone);} return $subject; inject Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface into constructor to access request object.
3. Use below coded to display on edit. Refer Magento\Backend\Block\System\Account\Edit\Form around this line $form->setValues($data);

Answer (score 4):

Replacing the statement

```
return parent::_prepareForm();
```

with this

```
return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic::_prepareForm();
```

worked for me. Here is the complete code. Adding the field "Accessible Store" as follow.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace [vendor]\[module]\Block\User\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\OptionInterface;

/**
 * Cms page edit form main tab
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Main extends \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface $localeLists
     * @param array $data
     * @param OptionInterface $deployedLocales Operates with deployed locales.
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface $localeLists,
        array $data = [],
        OptionInterface $deployedLocales = null
    ) {
        $this->deployedLocales = $deployedLocales
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(OptionInterface::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $authSession, $localeLists, $data, $this->deployedLocales);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form fields
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        //die('test');
        /** @var $model \Magento\User\Model\User */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('permissions_user');

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('user_');

        $baseFieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Account Information')]);

        if ($model->getUserId()) {
            $baseFieldset->addField('user_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'user_id']);
        } else {
            if (!$model->hasData('is_active')) {
                $model->setIsActive(1);
            }
        }

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'username',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'username',
                'label' => __('User Name'),
                'id' => 'username',
                'title' => __('User Name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'firstname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'firstname',
                'label' => __('First Name'),
                'id' => 'firstname',
                'title' => __('First Name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'lastname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'lastname',
                'label' => __('Last Name'),
                'id' => 'lastname',
                'title' => __('Last Name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        // Adding new field for Scope Access
        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'accessible_store',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'accessible_store',
                'label' => __('Accessible Store'),
                'id' => 'accessible_store',
                'title' => __('Accessible Store'),
                'class' => 'input-select',
                'options' => ['3' => __('Global Store'), 
                              '1' => __('Malaysia Pavillion'), 
                              '2' => __('Thailand Pavilion')],
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'email',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'email',
                'label' => __('Email'),
                'id' => 'customer_email',
                'title' => __('User Email'),
                'class' => 'required-entry validate-email',
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $isNewObject = $model->isObjectNew();
        if ($isNewObject) {
            $passwordLabel = __('Password');
        } else {
            $passwordLabel = __('New Password');
        }
        $confirmationLabel = __('Password Confirmation');
        $this->_addPasswordFields($baseFieldset, $passwordLabel, $confirmationLabel, $isNewObject);

        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'interface_locale',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'interface_locale',
                'label' => __('Interface Locale'),
                'title' => __('Interface Locale'),
                'values' => $this->deployedLocales->getOptionLocales(),
                'class' => 'select'
            ]
        );

        if ($this->_authSession->getUser()->getId() != $model->getUserId()) {
            $baseFieldset->addField(
                'is_active',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'is_active',
                    'label' => __('This account is'),
                    'id' => 'is_active',
                    'title' => __('Account Status'),
                    'class' => 'input-select',
                    'options' => ['1' => __('Active'), '0' => __('Inactive')]
                ]
            );
        }

        $baseFieldset->addField('user_roles', 'hidden', ['name' => 'user_roles', 'id' => '_user_roles']);

        $currentUserVerificationFieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'current_user_verification_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Current User Identity Verification')]
        );
        $currentUserVerificationFieldset->addField(
            self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD,
            'password',
            [
                'name' => self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD,
                'label' => __('Your Password'),
                'id' => self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD,
                'title' => __('Your Password'),
                'class' => 'input-text validate-current-password required-entry',
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $data = $model->getData();
        unset($data['password']);
        unset($data[self::CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_FIELD]);
        $form->setValues($data);

        $this->setForm($form);

        //return parent::_prepareForm();
        return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

And thanks @Rob for sharing the clue where to start with.

Comment: Thanks Brother, It's helped.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another working example, I've succeeded in overwriting the Website admin page. I was trying to add a URL field to the website edit page.

I did exactly what it's said in the validated answer but I didn't add a new fieldset. Instead, I've completed the existing one, using it's id defined in the Website class.

Besides, I'v used the inheritance to retrieve the website model and retrieve the current value from database to put it inside the form (It's copied from the Magento Website class too).

In prerequisite, it's needed to add the column `url` in the `store_website` table of the Magento database.

Here is the working result (tested in Magento 2.1) :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Store\Plugin\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form;

class Website extends \Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website
{
    /**
     * Get form HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {

            // From \Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website :
            $websiteModel = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('store_data');
            $postData = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('store_post_data');
            if ($postData) {
                $websiteModel->setData($postData['website']);
            }

            // Fieldset name from \Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website
            $fieldset = $form->getElement('website_fieldset');
            $fieldset->addField(
                'website_url',
                'text',
                [
                    'name' => 'website[url]', // From \Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website
                    'label' => __('Website URL'),
                    'value' => $websiteModel->getData('url'),
                    'title' => __('Website URL'),
                    'required' => false
                ]
            );

            $subject->setForm($form);
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

And the `di.xml` file in **Vendor/Store/etc/adminhtml** directory (nothing new here from the validated answer) :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website">
        <plugin name="admin_website_plugin" type="Vendor\Store\Plugin\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

after some research got a solution for this

> add new property "value" in addField method

with the value you need.
see the example:

```
        $fieldset->addField(
            'user_image',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'user_image',
                'label' => __('Image'),
                'id' => 'user_image',
                'title' => __('Image'),
                'value' => $value_that_you_need,
                'required' => false,
                'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, png'
            ]
        );
```

I hope it will help some of you ..

Answer (score 0):

I just did a minor change in your solution and it worked for me :

```
class Main extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
//Copied All the code in --- Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main
//added my own field in _prepareForm function

}
```

If you want, I can post the whole solution -- but I have to revise it because as per my company norms I cannot show the code on public forums. So just let me know if you can do it yourself.