# How to add new field to Admin User Info in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, user-roles

How can I add a new field which has an integer value into admin user info?

I want to add a dropdown on admin user edit form, to select any one admin user which has **'ABC' role**, and that will be saved with that admin user, for that, I found a way that we can add a new column into the **"admin/user" table** and save that selected value when admin user edited, not on admin user create.

How can achieve this functionality with the custom module?

> **I used below code and its saved manager id in table but in edit form it will not showing selected value. code as below :**

```
protected $manageData;

public function __construct(
    \Name\Module\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\ManageData $manageData
) {
    $this->manageData = $manageData;
}

/**
 * Get form HTML
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function aroundGetFormHtml(
    \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
)
{
    $form = $subject->getForm();
    if (is_object($form)) {
        $baseFieldset = $form->addFieldset('admin_manageData', ['legend' => __('Manager Information')]);
        $baseFieldset->addField(
            'manageData',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'manageData',
                'label' => __('Select Manager'),
                'title' => __('Select Manager'),
                'values' => $this->manageData->getAllOptions(), // it has array of all the admin users with role 'Manager' 
                'class' => 'select'
            ]
        );

        $subject->setForm($form);
    }

    return $proceed();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174209/magento-2-add-new-field-to-magento-user-admin-form ?

Comment: will it work with custom dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

Try following way:

```
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab;

class Main
{
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Get form HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {
            $baseFieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
            /** @var $model \Magento\User\Model\User */
            $model = $this->registry->registry('permissions_user');
            $data = $model->getData();
            $baseFieldset->addField(
                'manage_data',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'manage_data',
                    'label' => __('Select Manager'),
                    'title' => __('Select Manager'),
                    'options' => ['0' => __('--Select--'), '1' => __('Option 1'), '2' => __('Option 2'), '3' => __('Option 3')],
                    'class' => 'select',
                    'value' => isset($data['manage_data']) ? $data['manage_data'] : 0
                ]
            );

            $subject->setForm($form);
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Now new field will adding under **Account Information** fieldsets. Also value will be selected. I use **manage_data** column name.