# How to add custom field (textbox) in CMS page Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3

I want to add a custom field (textbox) on the cms page admin side. Can anyone please guide me?

Like this: https://prnt.sc/1qfe0cf

Comment: I don't have the time for an answer, but research extension attributes, where you can store that new value, and then add the field to the cms page layout config with a plugin. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174209/magento-2-add-new-field-to-magento-user-admin-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have have already installed module then use UpgradeSchema.php to add new field in cms_page table.

Otherwise please use InstallSchema.php file for new module.

> Step 1:- Please create file UpgradeSchema.php under path
> Vendor/Module/Setup/

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.0', '<')) {
            $this->addTextField($setup);
        }
    }

    protected function addTextField(SchemaSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();

        $connection->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('cms_page'),
            'sub_title',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Sub Title',
            ]
        );

        return $this;   
    }
}
```

> Step 2:- Change module version in file module.xml under path
> Vendor/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

> Step 3:- Please create file cms_page_form.xml under path
> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="sub_title" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Sub Title</label>
                <dataScope>sub_title</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**You will see Sub title field in admin with the use of above code. Also if you write anything in this new field. It will save in database as well. You don't need to do anything to save text field value in "cms_page" tabel.**

**Cheers!**

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much :) It is working like charm.